# How to make Hinton diagrams

Tags: machine-learning

I just start studying machine learning with Mathematica and, I want to know how make [Hinton diagrams](http://tonysyu.github.io/mpltools/auto_examples/special/plot_hinton.html). Can someone give an idea, please?

Comment: Can you 1) define Hinton diagrams; 2) provide an example or a link to one; 3) provide sample data to generate such a diagram?

Answer (score 6):

Look up [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) and [`Rectangle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle.html).  The following is a starting point that you can improve on.

```
hinton[matrix_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Graphics[
  MapIndexed[
   Style[
     Rectangle[#2 - Abs[#1] {1, 1}/2, #2 + Abs[#1] {1, 1}/2], 
     GrayLevel@UnitStep[#1]
   ] &, 
   matrix, 
   {2}
  ],
  Background -> GrayLevel[1/2],
  opt
 ]

matrix = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {30, 30}];

hinton[matrix]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A variation using  [`Translate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate.html) + [`Scale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scale.html) with graphics primitive and colors as input:

```
ClearAll[sTS, hintonPlot]

sTS[prim_: Rectangle[], cols_: {White, Black}] :=
   {cols[[2 - UnitStep[#]]], Translate[Scale[prim, Abs@{#, #}], #2]} &;

hintonPlot[prim_: Rectangle[], cols_: {White, Black}] := 
  Graphics[MapIndexed[sTS[prim, cols], #, {2}], ##2, Background -> GrayLevel[1/2]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1]
mat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {30, 30}];

Row[{hintonPlot[][mat, ImageSize -> 400], 
  hintonPlot[Disk[], {White, Red}][mat/2,
    ImageSize -> 400, Background -> Black]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
hintonPlot[WindingPolygon[CirclePoints[5][[{1, 3, 5, 2, 4}]]]][
 RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}]/2, Background -> Red, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
hintonPlot[][RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {40, 20}], Background -> Red, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]